# import openai fails (python): cannot import name 'COMMON_SAFE_ASCII_CHARACTERS'

Tags: python, openai-api

Trying to use openai:

```
import openai
```

I've got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 70, in <module>
    import cchardet as chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cchardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../chat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openai
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources import (
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_resources/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openai.api_resources.audio import Audio  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_resources/audio.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openai import api_requestor, util
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 21, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .client_reqrep import (
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 72, in <module>
    import charset_normalizer as chardet  # type: ignore[no-redef]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/charset_normalizer/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from charset_normalizer.api import from_fp, from_path, from_bytes, normalize
  File "/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/charset_normalizer/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from charset_normalizer.md import mess_ratio
  File "charset_normalizer/md.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'COMMON_SAFE_ASCII_CHARACTERS' from 'charset_normalizer.constant' (/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/charset_normalizer/constant.py)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a dependancy problem. Install charset-normalizer version 2.1.0:

```
python -m pip install charset-normalizer==2.1.0
```